# What does "pesas un huevo" mean?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, expresiones, coloquialismos, vulgaridades

I am trying to figure out what `pesas un huevo` means.  I know that `huevos` sometimes translates to testicles, so is this sexual/vulgar?

Comment: Is there any context? In Chile is common expression "pesas menos que un huevo", which means that _you have no authority or power_.

Answer (score 6):

Huevos besides testicles is also used as a intensifier. So the phrase:

> Pesas un huevo.

is translated as:

> You're heavy as hell.

You can use it with lot of things.

> Me importa un huevo. [In don't give a shit]
>
> Me costó un huevo. [It was hard as shit]
>
> Caminé un huevo. [I walked a lot]

And yes, it's vulgar, but pretty normal.

Comment: I agree that is vulgar, but I don't think is as rude as the English word "fuck". I think is more like "Shit" (e.g. from your examples: "I don't give a shit"). Also "Me costó un huevo" has some ambiguity: "It was difficult as hell to do"  vs. "It was so damn expensive".

Comment: I agree with you, I'll change that.

Comment: It's definitely not just Mexican, though.

Comment: I'll change that too, where are you from?

Comment: I'm from the US, but speak Spain Spanish (un variante asturmadrileño).  From what I can tell reading on-line, Argentina and Chile also use it.  It can also mean very little as much as it can mean a lot: *cuesta un huevo* (muchísimo) vs *me importa un huevo* (poquísimo).

Answer (score 1):

In Spain, it's equivalent to "pesas mucho". In English it would be "You're very weighty"

Answer (score 1):

We use that phrase here too, in Andalusia. And yes, it's translated to:

> You're heavy as hell.

Answer (score 1):

Is the equivalent as your are weighty - same as "pesas mucho" o "estas super pesado"

Comment: "estas super pesado" could be understood as something closer to "you are so annoying", e.g. "Estas super pesado con lo de tu amigo Luis. Quieres cambiar el tema ya, por favor?"

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas expresiones sobre partes del cuerpo que se usan en el sentido de "un precio muy alto":

Ese coche cuesta un ojo de la cara.

Ese coche cuesta un riñón.

Ese coche cuesta un huevo [en el sentido de un testículo].

La expresión "un huevo", al contrario que las demás, ha extendido su uso a otros contextos con el sentido general de "mucho":

Trabajas un huevo, pesas un huevo (trabajas mucho, pesas mucho).

Posiblemente, estas expresiones provengan de antiguos castigos o penas:

Ese crimen te costará la cabeza, el cuello, un ojo de la cara [= como castigo te cortarán la cabeza, te cortarán el cuello, te sacarán un ojo de la cara].